# www redirection for co.in and co.uk

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2.2, no-www

Anyone please help me to redirect in apache webserver

My domains which have .co.in  extensions

http://domain.co.in should be redirected to http://www.domain.co.in

Comment: Possible duplicate of dozens of other questions, but I can't find a suitable one so I'll just answer it.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite just this domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.in$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

To rewrite for multiple domains in one rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1  [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: The webpage at http://www.kalthura-expert.co.cc/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: @Bastian Vs on which? The single or multi-domain rule?  You entered it exactly as above? It would behave that way if the `!` was omitted.

Comment: @Basitan Vs are your domains setup as separate VirtualHosts in Apache,or are they ServerAlias to the same VirtualHost?

Answer (score 1):

create a .htaccess in the web root,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.in [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.co.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: thats odd, we've been using this in production environments on servers for years. I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: @MCannon It has to be his Apache misconfiguration -- your rule is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need mod-rewrite complexity to do that, the most basic configuration will do the job better (simplier=better).

Make one Virtualhost, containing all domains to be redirected (one in `ServerName` the others in `ServerAlias`). Inside it use `Redirect` to the right one, where you use only one ServerName.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 />
   # catch all DNS to be redirected here
   ServerName redirect.domain.co.in
   ServerAlias domain.co.in
   ServerAlias domain.org
   ServerAlias domain_co_in.com

   Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.co.in/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 />
    # The real VH with only one name
    ServerName www.domain.co.in
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
```